# Multiple local processes have the same socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm a bit of a socket/net code newbie, so this may be a stupid question.

I'm running multiple local "clients" and a local "server" using the AF_INET protocol.

However, when I try and all clients to the server, they appear to be connecting on the same socket, making reading from a single nonsensical.

The below code demonstrates the issue, independent of any server code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sockfd;     // socket file descriptor

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    std::cout<<"socket is "<<sockfd<<std::endl;

    /* perform various i/o tasks */

    return 0;
}
```

The socket here is always `3` no matter how many of these processes are running.

Is this expected? If so, then what might be the best way to go about this sort of thing as I'd like to use internet protocol to allow the same functionality over my local network or online.

Comment: `socket` returns a file descriptor, which is always process-exclusive by default. This is normal and doesn't affect how many connections you can make on the loopback interface.

Comment: _"when I try and all clients to the server"_? _"they appear to be connecting on the same socket, making reading from a single nonsensical"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is expected; [file descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) — at least, POSIX-compliant ones — are doled out by your OS on a per-process basis:

> Generally, a file descriptor is an index for an entry in a kernel-resident array data structure containing the details of open files. In POSIX this data structure is called a file descriptor table, and each process has its own file descriptor table. The process passes the file descriptor to the kernel through a system call, and the kernel will access the file on behalf of the process. The process itself cannot read or write the file descriptor table directly.
>
> On Linux, the set of file descriptors open in a process can be accessed under the path /proc/PID/fd/, where PID is the process identifier.
>
> In Unix-like systems, file descriptors can refer to any Unix file type named in a file system. As well as regular files, this includes directories, block and character devices (also called "special files"), Unix domain sockets, and named pipes. File descriptors can also refer to other objects that do not normally exist in the file system, such as anonymous pipes and network sockets.

So in your case, more than likely, the following are already assigned by default:

- `0` stdin
- `1` stdout
- `2` stderr

So the first you request yourself becomes `3`.

You do not need to worry about this whatsoever. FD 3 on process 1100 is entirely distinct from FD 3 on process 1101. This will not cause problems for your code or your client/server system. You could probably have just tested to find that out.

Comment: This is something I frequently forget on POSIX,  thanks for the reminder. It looks like I have other unrelated issues causing my problem then.

Answer (score 1):

The number returned by `socket` is *not* a socket number, it's just an opaque index into a table maintained by the OS and/or language runtime. Each process will have its own table, so it's normal for those numbers to be duplicated, nothing to worry about.

You can use [`getsockname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) to get extended information about the socket itself, such as the port number.